# Unit test cases for event

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write unit test cases for the the below function:

```js
selected (event:any) {
  let selectedValue = event.target.value.substring(0,3);
  this.seletedBatch = selectedValue;
  this.enableSubmitButton = true
}
```

The test cases which I have written:

```js
let selectedValue= fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('selectedValue')
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.selectedBatch).toEqual(selectedValue)
expect (component.enableSubmitButton).toBe(true)
```

But I'm getting the following errors and not sure if I'm writing it correctly for this event:

```
1. Expected undefined to equal null. 
2. Expected false to be true
```

P.S - I'm new in writing test cases.

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you also include the errors that you get in the body of your question?

Comment: 1. Expected undefined to equal null.
2. Expected false to be true.

Comment: Seems the `selectedValue` is not rendered, if it's under any condition (*ngIf)?. How you call `selected` in your test case file. More line of code in your .spec file would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Usually testing goes like this:

```js
// 1. Arrange
// here goes everything you already did to set the test up
// fixture, dependencies, etc
let testValue = 'test';
let expectedValue = 'tes';

// 2. Act
component.selected({ target: { value: testValue } });
fixture.detectChanges();

// 3. Assert  
expect(component.selectedBatch).toEqual(expectedValue);
expect(component.enableSubmitButton).toBe(true);
```